# Recording and saving audio based on click event android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I want to create app in which when i click on button, audio recording should start for particular time (5s) and then I can save to a folder of the app or somewhere in my phone or use the file directly in the next steps. Specifically, I will record an audio file in 5 seconds, then start to recognize by my word recognition algorithm and execute the following commands. Please help me at the step of recording and saving files. Thank you guys for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) api for android. You can record, save and use the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But now if i don't want to save or play, can i use the recorded file directly? If I save to the raw folder, will I be able to overwrite the old file after I record? I just want to record the wav file and use it as an input object of the function

Comment: If you are just looking to save the file temporarily, you can use `getExternalFilesDir()`  or `getExternalCacheDir()`. It will save you file to a folder private to your app on the device. You can access and modify (delete or rewrite) the file as you like.

Checkout [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) for more info on various locations and ways that you can save a file in android file system.